# Make usergroups able to authorize User Account Control Prompt

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, users, groups, uac

I was wondering how you could make a group in Active Directory that is allowed to elevate/authorize programs with their credentials without setting them as the built in administrator?
Windows server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UAC prompt can only be approved and grant administrative rights to a user that is a member of the local `Administrators` group. You can easily set domain accounts - or even domain groups - as member of the local administrators group. This can be done directly or via policy.

Also note that some UAC prompts actually don't need full administrative credentials - a standard user can provide their own and have a lot of software packages still install, just in a per user mode.

Comment: I just want them to be able to install softwares and change some certain setting i think Administrator group has too much access to stuff. @TimBrigham